# Amp on washer is 10amps but how can I tell if it has the correct gauge wire for 20amp breaker?

Tags: washing-machine

There is a gfci outlet that keeps popping.  I am not sure the amps on it but it did this on day 1 of install years ago.  I was going to replace the gfci as the washer is only 10 amps found the model here

https://www.lg.com/us/washers/lg-WM2140CW-front-load-washer?bvstate=pg:9/ct:q

**It only trips when we click the start button and never anytime else**

I was thinking of throwing a 20amp gfci in the wall but I was worried the wiring in the washer can't take it?   Are washing machines made to be plugged into 20amp as well as 15 amp circuits?

or is the washer the one determining how many amps is pulled and we are only tripping the socket so the wires in the walls don't burn out...ie. can't run a 20amp device on a 15 amp circuit as the breaker will pop to keep the wires safe since they are thickness for 15 amps.

thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

GFCI and regular circuit breakers interrupt power to a circuit. The effect is the same: everything stops working. But the reasons - and the fixes - are entirely different.

#### Regular Circuit Breaker

A typical US washing machine is designed for a 15A 120V circuit. In newer homes, the laundry room will typically have a 20A 120V circuit. That helps in certain situations, for example if you want to use an iron on the same circuit as the washing machine, while the washing machine is running. But where 15A or 20A, a circuit with a 10A appliance will rarely trip the regular circuit breaker, because 10A < 15A. There are exceptions, such as a stalled motor, where the circuit breaker *will* trip. But that's extremely unlikely to be happening when you press the start button, as most washing machines don't run the main motor at startup.

In addition, a 20A circuit can have 15A receptacles (as long as there are at least two receptacles), so you may have a 20A circuit anyway.

Is it *possible* that you have a 15A circuit rather than a 20A circuit? Yes. If you do, you probably, but not necessarily, only have 14 AWG wire, so you can't upgrade it to 20A without replacing the wire. But it doesn't matter, because that's not your problem.

#### GFCI

A GFCI is a Ground Fault Circuit Interrupter. It specifically looks for an imbalance between hot and neutral (or between 2 hots on a 240V circuit, which is not the case here). A GFCI will be rated for the size of the circuit, but it is a safe bet that all included with 15A duplex receptacles can handle 20A without a problem, because they may need to do so when including down-line protection. In any case, over-current will *not* trip a GFCI. Push 20A through a 15A GFCI receptacle and the circuit breaker may or may not trip, but the GFCI will be unaffected. Push 25A through and the circuit breaker will trip eventually (unless something is seriously wrong), but the GFCI *still* won't trip.

But get even a tiny imbalance between hot and neutral, and the GFCI *will* trip. This imbalance can be due to a connection between neutral and ground (in and of itself harmless, but can be dangerous in certain circumstances) or a connection between hot and ground (very dangerous!). These connections can be intermittent, due to loose connections, frayed insulation or other problems. They can also be due to water bridging contacts - when the water dries up, the problem goes away for a while.

Based on description, you are getting a GFCI trip. Because this is a wet area with a device that handles water, the concern is quite real. It is *possible* you have a faulty GFCI. But more likely is a faulty appliance - loose connection, water seeping into areas where it should not go, etc. Unfortunately, the time to deal with this through the manufacture was "day 1". Since that was years ago, the manufacturer may be of some help but it won't be covered under the warranty.

You can try swapping the GFCI/receptacle, as that is a $20 fix that may work. But if it doesn't work then you are still back to an appliance problem. With more specific details (brand, model, etc.) it may be possible to narrow down the source of the problem.

Comment: I assumed since the breaker is 20A that the wire is fine in the wall but have not checked that one.  I installed breakers before (my house has a master shutoff thankfully), but never checked and I am the original owner of the house so the builder installed those.

Comment: yes, the brand of the model is in the link I posted actually as I was curious on the specs.

Comment: Also, THANK YOU for the writeup.  This is amazing!!!!!  I didn't realize that was the difference and when I did the basement gfci install (brand new bathroom and completely dry), it kept tripping over and over and I bought a new one and then it worked like a charm.  I guess I will try a quick gfci install and see if that works first. thanks!  (House is 2005 so perhaps by then they did most laundry rooms with a 20A type guage wire...I think that is 12 guage if I recall and 14 guage for 15 amp)

Comment: Try a different brand of GFCI. In *some* cases a GFCI may be either too sensitive or influenced by factors that shouldn't *really* trip it, though I would expect that more with AFCI than with GFCI. (Do *not* put in an AFC+GFCI+receptacle - the AFCI is not a good match for motor loads, unless required by local code).

Comment: Worked like a charm!!!!! OMG, this is so much nicer.  now onto the damn some breaker that is broken(on but is definitely off as socket is not working).  I need to post a separate question for that.  THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!